# System.TypeLoadException in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, .net, maui

Could you please provide us any resolution over this critical issue in .NET MAUI:

> System.TypeLoadException System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000004 from typeref (expected class 'System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')

> System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributesBase(ICustomAttributeProvider , Type , Boolean ) System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider , Type , Boolean ) System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type , Boolean )

[image]

Comment: Is it a default MAUI project? Or  is there any third party nuget in your project?

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you're trying to do and what you've done that leads to this error. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post all *relevant* code, project info and error messages as *text* only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it is defult MAUI while app using happend app crash log on app center. but i unable to reproduce this issue our end. as current.net 7 app version.

Comment: Hi @Julian, this is issue logged on app center in .NET 7 MAUI. while using app it's occursing. do let me know resolution.

Comment: hi @Community, this issue occur on app center logs while app using, i need resolution.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don't provide more information. This question will likely get closed until further information is provided.